# How to add more script files in Google Web Starter Kit?

Tags: babeljs, google-web-starter-kit

I am trying to start a new project with Web Starter Kit from Google. Thing is if I add another script alongside the main.js, then it doesn't seem to be compiled to dist folder, nor included inside the main.js

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `gulpfile.babel.js

"Since we are not using useref in the scripts build pipeline, you need to explicitly list your scripts here in the right order to be correctly concatenated"